# SQL: Filtering a query with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

As I'm sure you'll be able to tell from this question, I am very new and unfamiliar with SQL. After quite some time (and some help from this wonderful website) I was able to create a query that lists almost exactly what I want:

```
Select p1.user.Office, 
p1.user.Loc_No, 
p1.user.Name, 
p1.user.Code, 
p1.user.Default_Freq, 
(Select distinct MAX(p2.pay.Paycheck_PayDate) 
from p2.pay
where p1.user.Client_TAS_CL_UNIQUE = p2.pay.CL_UniqueID) as Last_Paycheck

from
PR.client 

where 
p1.user.Client_End_Date is null
and p1.user.Client_Region = 'Z'
and p1.user.Client_Office <> 'ZF'
and substring(p1.user. Code,2,1) <> '0'
```

Now I just need to filter this slightly more using the following logic:

If Default_Freq = 'W' then only output clients with a Last_Paycheck 7 or more days past the current date

If Default_Freq = 'B' then only output clients with a Last_Paycheck 14 or more days past the current date

Etc., Etc.

I know this is possible, but I have no clue how the syntax should start. I believe I would need to use a Case statement inside the Where clause? Any help is greatly appreciated as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT

X.p1.user.Office, 
X.p1.user.Loc_No, 
X.p1.user.Name, 
X.p1.user.Code, 
X.Default_Freq, 
X.Last_Paycheck

FROM

(Select 
p1.user.Office, 
p1.user.Loc_No, 
p1.user.Name, 
p1.user.Code, 
p1.user.Default_Freq AS Default_Freq, 
(Select distinct MAX(p2.pay.Paycheck_PayDate) 
from p2.pay
where p1.user.Client_TAS_CL_UNIQUE = p2.pay.CL_UniqueID) as Last_Paycheck

from
PR.client 

where 
p1.user.Client_End_Date is null
and p1.user.Client_Region = 'Z'
and p1.user.Client_Office <> 'ZF'
and substring(p1.user. Code,2,1) <> '0') X
WHERE (
      (X.Default_Freq = 'W' AND (DATEDIFF ( d , X.Last_Paycheck , @currentDate) >= 7))
      OR (X.Default_Freq = 'B' AND (DATEDIFF ( d , X.Last_Paycheck , @currentDate) >= 14))
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This seems like it is exactly what I need, but I am getting the following error: Invalid column name 'Last_Paycheck'.. Is it because I created Last_Paycheck in the subquery at the top of my code? How do I recall a column name that is created within the query? Sorry for being such a noob!

Answer (score 0):

Use your current query as a derived table or a CTE (CTEs exists for SQL Server 2005+). And then you can do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    --- Your current query here
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE (Default_Freq = 'W' AND DATEDIFF(DAY,Last_Paycheck,GETDATE()) >= 7)
OR (Default_Freq = 'B' AND DATEDIFF(DAY,Last_Paycheck,GETDATE()) >= 14)
OR () -- keep going
```

Comment: Same as above, it says Last_Paycheck is invalid column name.. How can this be referenced correctly?

Comment: @user2748206 it shouldn't give you that message, since that column is defined on the CTE. Are you sure that you did what was posted on the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make a case statement, and put that in your where clause.

I.e. (off the top of my head):

```
CASE 
  WHEN (Default_Freq = 'W' AND DATEDIFF(DAY,Last_Paycheck,GETDATE()) >= 7) THEN 1
  WHEN (Default_Freq = 'B' AND DATEDIFF(DAY,Last_Paycheck,GETDATE()) >= 14) THEN 1
ELSE 0 END = 1
```

Comment: Same as below, it says Last_Paycheck is invalid column name.. How can this be referenced correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try this with inner query:

```
select * from (
  Select 
    p1.user.Office, 
    p1.user.Loc_No, 
    p1.user.Name, 
    p1.user.Code, 
    p1.user.Default_Freq, 
    (Select distinct MAX(p2.pay.Paycheck_PayDate) 
     from p2.pay
     where p1.user.Client_TAS_CL_UNIQUE = p2.pay.CL_UniqueID) as Last_Paycheck
  from PR.client 
  where p1.user.Client_End_Date is null
    and p1.user.Client_Region = 'Z'
    and p1.user.Client_Office <> 'ZF'
    and substring(p1.user. Code,2,1) <> '0') t
where (
     (Default_Freq = 'W' AND (DATEDIFF ( d , Last_Paycheck , @currentDate) <= 7))
  OR (Default_Freq = 'B' AND (DATEDIFF ( d , Last_Paycheck , @currentDate) <= 14))
)
```